# Find Replace quotes only around single words

Tags: excel

I need to remove the quotes that are around single words only, keeping the ones around double words.

SO...

"Orange","Yellow Banana","Red Apple"
Should be this:
Orange,"Yellow Banana","Red Apple"

AND

"Yellow Banana","Red Apple","Orange"
should be this:
"Yellow Banana","Red Apple",Orange

Comment: Is each word/group of words in a separate cell (i.e. A1=`"Orange"`, A2=`"Yellow Banana"`, ...) or is the whole string in a single cell (i.e. A1=`"Orange","Yellow Banana",...`)?

Comment: it would be simple if you can use regex (e.g. Notepad++ or some VBA code) - replace `"([^", ]+)"` with `\1` (1st capture group)

Comment: Single Cell - I do have notepad++ and could copy in and back out, the criteria you pasted isn't working in notepad++ though.

Comment: I wouldn't be against using text to columns via comma to separate, and re-concatenate, but with up to 6 values between commas, I still don't have a great way remove quotes from only the single words...

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick go, this works but its less than optimal :) if your list isnt formatted properly (missing spaces, or extra punctuation)

You didn't specify where the text was or how your accessing it so just did whatever :)

```
Public Sub fixQuotes(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Words() As String
Dim Word As String
Dim Index As Long
Dim Result As String

Words = Split(Target.Value, " ")

Result = ""

For Index = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
    Word = Words(Index)

    Word = Replace(Word, ",", "")
    Word = Replace(Word, ".", "")

    If Left(Word, 1) = Chr(34) And Right(Word, 1) = Chr(34) Then

        Result = Result & Replace(Words(Index), Chr(34), "") & " "

    Else

        Result = Result & Words(Index) & " "

    End If

Next Index

Target.Value = Result

End Sub
```

After looking at your examples i see that the previous one will not work well if at all (it needs spaces between the list items)

So I've made a new one :)

```
Public Function fixQuotes2(ByVal Text As String) As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim Character As String
Dim Quote As Boolean
Dim A As Integer
Dim Result As String

Index = 1

Do

    If Mid(Text, Index, 1) = Chr(34) And Index < Len(Text) Then
        A = 1
        Quote = False
        Do
            Character = Mid(Text, Index + A, 1)

            If Character = " " Then
                Quote = True
            End If
            If Character = Chr(34) Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                If Index + 1 >= Len(Text) Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    A = A + 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        If Quote = True Then
            Result = Result & Mid(Text, Index, A + 1)
        Else
            Result = Result & Mid(Text, Index + 1, A - 1)
        End If
        Index = Index + A + 1
    Else
        If Index >= Len(Text) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Result = Result & Mid(Text, Index, 1)
            Index = Index + 1
        End If
    End If
Loop

    fixQuotes2 = Result

End Function
```

This one you can use as a worksheet function unlike the first.

note: make sure you've saved your stuff before trying it! (had a few infinite loops when making it :p)

```
Public Sub fixMacro()
ActiveCell.Value = fixQuotes2(CStr(ActiveCell.Value))
End Sub
```

Adding this along with fixQuotes2 you will get "fixMacro" in your macros list, when you run the macro it will run the function on the active cell, replacing its value with the fixed version.

Comment: I've only used/recorded a few macros..I just pasted this into a new module in my workbook, but it's not showing up in my sheet's macros..any ideas?

Comment: First, thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it! I'm still not getting it to show in my macros once I save and exit MS visual basic though..

Comment: Ah, my bad. Its currently a function which you can use in a forumula in your worksheet. eg: "=fixQuotes2(A1)" where A1 is the source text and the cell when you put that will contain the fixed version

Comment: Oh perfect! Sorry for the delay, but this works perfectly and was a life saver, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeQuoteSingleWords()

    Dim c As Range, arr, x

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        arr = Split(Trim(c.Value), ",")
        For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            arr(x) = Trim(arr(x))
            If InStr(arr(x), " ") = 0 Then
                arr(x) = Replace(arr(x), """", "")
            End If
        Next x
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Join(arr, ", ")
    Next c

End Sub
```